# Aligning table headers to the bottom

Tags: tables, context

I have a table with table headings (which are rotated 90 degrees clockwise because of their length) that needs to be aligned to the bottom. How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
\starttext    
\starttable[s1|cp(.05\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|]
    \HL
    \VL \VL \VL \VL \VL \TWO \mbox{Afzonderlijke} \\ \mbox{productieprijs} \VL \TWO \mbox{Algemene} \\ \mbox{productieprijs} \VL \VL \AR
    \DC \DC \DC \DC \DL[4] \DC \DR
    \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~Bodemsoort}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~Kap. invest. in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~Gemid. winst in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vss \rotate[90]{~Product in 100 kg}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~v/h gehele product in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~van 100 kg in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~van 100 kg in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~v/h gehele product in \$}} \VL \vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill \rotate[90]{~Differentiële rente I in \$}} \VL \AR
\HL
\VL I   \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 4 \VL 120 \VL 30 \VL 30 \VL 120 \VL 0  \VL \AR
\VL II  \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 5 \VL 120 \VL 24 \VL 30 \VL 150 \VL 30 \VL \AR
\VL III \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 6 \VL 120 \VL 20 \VL 30 \VL 180 \VL 60 \VL \AR
\HL
\stoptable
\stoptext
```

And here a picture of how it looks now:

[image: Table with rotated headings, but aligned to top]

(note: the table is gray because I used a background there).

btw. The headings in the upper two boxes seem also a bit misaligned, the 'p'-tails touch the horizontal lines. Anyway to correct this (other then using the new table layout formats)?

Comment: Coukd we have a full compilable code to test? I don't even where `\starttable` comes from.

Comment: I've added the `\starttext` and `\stoptext`, so the example is now a full example (in Context).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Natural Tables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE) for such tables as it provides a much cleaner separation of content and presentation.

```
\startsetups table:formatting
  \setupTABLE[each][each][width=0.1\textwidth, align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off, leftframe=on, rightframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][1,2][frame=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][2][align={middle,low}]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on]
\stopsetups

\define\tablerotate{\dontleavehmode\rotate[rotation=90, location=normal]}

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups={table:formatting}]
\NC \NC \NC \NC \NC[nc=2] Afzonderlijke \\ productieprijs \NC[nc=2] Algemene \\ productieprijs \NC \NC \NR
\NC \tablerotate{Bodemsoort} \NC \tablerotate{Kap. invest. in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Gemid. winst in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Product in 100 kg} \NC \tablerotate{v/h gehele product in \$} \NC \tablerotate{van 100 kg in \$} \NC \tablerotate{van 100 kg in \$} \NC \tablerotate{v/h gehele product in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Differentiële rente I in \$} \NC \NR
\NC I   \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 4 \NC 120 \NC 30 \NC 30 \NC 120 \NC 0  \NC \NR
\NC II  \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 5 \NC 120 \NC 24 \NC 30 \NC 150 \NC 30 \NC \NR
\NC III \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 6 \NC 120 \NC 20 \NC 30 \NC 180 \NC 60 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. At least this fixes the `p-tail` problem which touch the horzontal lines, which looks ugly. I should get used to always use the new table commands. I assume it is possible also to get rid of the extra horizontal lines, because I only want the horizontal lines right under the two cells on top wich contain text, not the others. (please don't tell and let me figure out myself).

Answer (score 0):

I see now where I made a mistake, I added `\vtop{\phantom{x} \vfill .. }` to the header elements, if I delete that code, and the unnecessary `~` before each header, the table looks just fine.

```
\starttext
\starttable[s0|cp(.05\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|cp(.1\textwidth)|]
\HL
\VL \VL \VL \VL \VL \TWO \mbox{Afzonderlijke} \\ \mbox{productieprijs} \VL \TWO \mbox{Algemene} \\ \mbox{productieprijs} \VL \VL \AR
\DC \DC \DC \DC \DL[4] \DC \DR
\VL \rotate[90]{Bodemsoort} \VL \rotate[90]{Kap. invest. in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{Gemid. winst in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{Product in 100 kg} \VL \rotate[90]{v/h gehele product in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{van 100 kg in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{van 100 kg in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{v/h gehele product in \$} \VL \rotate[90]{Differentiële rente I in \$} \VL \AR
\HL
\VL I   \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 4 \VL 120 \VL 30 \VL 30 \VL 120 \VL 0  \VL \AR
\VL II  \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 5 \VL 120 \VL 24 \VL 30 \VL 150 \VL 30 \VL \AR
\VL III \VL 100 \VL 20 \VL 6 \VL 120 \VL 20 \VL 30 \VL 180 \VL 60 \VL \AR
\HL
\stoptable
\stoptext
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aditya I found the following more satisfying solution, using new table commands:

```
% setup for the table

\startsetups table:grondrente
  \setupTABLE[each][each][width=0.11\textwidth, align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[each][each][frame=off, leftframe=on, rightframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][1,2][background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]
  \setupTABLE[row][1][topframe=on]
  \setupTABLE[row][2][bottomframe=on,align={middle,low}]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][bottomframe=on]
\stopsetups

% Table definition

\startTABLE[setups={table:grondrente}]
\NC \NC \NC \NC \NC[nc=2] Afzonderlijke \\ productieprijs \NC[nc=2] Algemene \\ productieprijs \NC \NC \NR
\NC \tablerotate{Bodemsoort} \NC \tablerotate{Kap. invest. in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Gemid. winst in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Product in 100 kg} \NC \tablerotate{v/h gehele product in \$} \NC \tablerotate{van 100 kg in \$} \NC \tablerotate{van 100 kg in \$} \NC \tablerotate{v/h gehele product in \$} \NC \tablerotate{Differentiële rente I in \$} \NC \NR
\NC I   \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 4 \NC 120 \NC 30 \NC 30 \NC 120 \NC ~0 \NC \NR
\NC II  \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 5 \NC 120 \NC 24 \NC 30 \NC 150 \NC 30 \NC \NR
\NC III \NC 100 \NC 20 \NC 6 \NC 120 \NC 20 \NC 30 \NC 180 \NC 60 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
```

The result you can see below:

[image]

I've corrected the horizontal bottom lines in row 1 that shouldn't be displayed and the allignment of the "0" in the last column of the 3-rd row (1st data row). Although that solution is not generic, and only works here because the width of the number in a column is everywhere the same per column, except that case.

How would one do that if that weren't the case? I mean, still displaying the numbers somewhat middle aligned in each cell (some space at least between the final digit of the number and the right border of each cell), while the alignment between numbers of different rows of the same column is correct (vertical alignment according to the position of the decimal point, even when that decimal point is omitted). Aligning them all to the right (flush right) would do the trick for numbers without decimal point, although one would want like to have some extra space between the number and the right border of the cell.